# Cannot connect to openfire server in android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

whenever I tries to run my app this error comes:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method 
 domainprep(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/jxmpp/stringprep/XmppStringPrepUtil; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringPrepUtil' appears in /data/data/app.com.hideout.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jxmpp-core-0.3.0_6be45a45890e0c107a4cb82dbe4a33060e3b5f11-classes.dex)
```

Tries searching on google, also imported the jar for these nothing worked.

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.hideout.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/smack-tcp-4.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/smack-android-extensions-4.1.0-beta1.jar')
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to connect to xmpp server which is openfire

```
private class MyLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a connection to the jabber.org server.
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = null;
        try {
            config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                     .setXmppDomain(SERVICE)
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
                    .setHost(HOST)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setPort(PORT)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true) // to view what's happening in detail
                    .build();
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            Log.e("app",e.getMessage()+"");
        }

        AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        try {
            conn1.connect();
            if(conn1.isConnected()) {
                Log.w("app", "conn done");
            }
            conn1.login();

            if(conn1.isAuthenticated()) {
                Log.w("app", "Auth done");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("app", e.toString());
        }

        return "";
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: don´t use the jar file....it´s better to import usually via gradle like explained in the documentation: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: i'm not using it right now ...plz see my gradle file

Comment: if you get error from `conn1.connect()`, then your configuration is wrong.

Comment: of course you are using a jar file...`compile files('libs/smack-tcp-4.2.0.jar')` refers to a jar file. So if you don´t use one, you have to change the configartion. As I said, follow the Documents and everything is good.

Comment: thanks @Opiatefuchs....earlier I was using dependencies offline...that helped